# Zero-mean RV $X$, probability of being positive using moments

Tags: probability, self-study, moments, probability-inequalities

For zero-mean RV $X$ with finite fourth moment, prove that 
$$
P(X>0)\ge \frac{\mathbb{E}(X^2)^2}{4\mathbb{E}(X^4)}
$$

I tried Chebyshev with adding $t$ to both sides, but I could not get fourth moment.

Comment: Please add the self-study tag. Also, what is $t$?

Comment: just some positive constant, but then I obtained upperbound to be 1...

Comment: Cross post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2670505/zero-mean-rv-with-finite-fourth-moment-probability-of-being-positive.

Comment: @Ethan, I see that you have created a lot of cross posted questions on the math and stat stack-exchange sub-sites. Could you flag them asking the moderators to combine these questions since cross-posts are not beneficial for the network?

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Answer (score 1):

We can find find in literature ([F.D. Lesley and V. Rotar](https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/article337.html?sid=337)) that:

$$P (X \geq 0) \geq \frac{2 \sqrt {3}-3}{E (X^4)}$$

if X has variance equal to 1. What is left for you to do is find out how this inequality scales when that condition is not true, and maybe see whether the $X\geq0$ instead of $X>0$ is not troubling.